# JavaScript global variable definition inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable `a` and I am using it inside a function and assigning a value to it. When I use this variable outside the function it gives me `undefined`.

Eg.:

```
var a;
function my_func(){
  a=5;
}
console.log(a); //outputs undefined, how do I get the value 5 here
```

Why do I get `undefined` instead of `5`?

---

It dint resolve my issue.

```
var id;

function set_id(myid){
 id=myid;
}

function get_id(){
 return id;
}

$("#btn").click(function(){
 $.post("....", function(data){ //data reurns a JSON
  set_id(id); //success!!
 }
}

$("#show").click(function()[
 console.log(get_id()); //doesn't work, how do I get this workin.. Where am I going wrong
}
```

Comment: before consoling the variable, you need to call the function, my_func(); untill then var a will be  undefined.

Answer (score 3):

you should call the function `my_func` before log:

```
var a;
function my_func(){
  a=5;
}
my_func();      //<-- here
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a;

function my_function1() {
    return 5;
}

function my_function2() {
    a = 5;
}

/* Either of these options below will work to change the value of "a" to 5*/

// a = my_function1()
// my_function2()​​​
```